# Android Studio installed and now Google Chrome won't work

Tags: android, android-studio

So I downloaded Android Studio. To make that work I had to create a JAVA_HOME path to the jdk. After doing that Android Studio worked. I came back later and Google Chrome no longer works. I've done everything. Virus scans, uninstall reinstall, changing "default" folder name to recreate a new one. How can I fix this?

Comment: does Google Chrome throw any error?

Comment: @PriyankGupta no it does not. I click on it and the wheel spins and then it just never opens. I have checked the task manager and there isn't one running. I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: have you tried this? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142061?hl=en

Comment: Kill background chrome process, Try run it using Administrator rights. If it wont work try running with disabled plugin http://superuser.com/a/822449

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar neither of these worked. I'm going to uninstall android studio and start over

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the JAVA_Home file and uninstalling Android Studio. I ran a check disk. Booted back, Chrome worked. Re-did the JAVA_Home and then reinstalled Android Studio.